# How can I wirelessly transfer video from iPhone to Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, video, data-transfer

I took some video on my iPhone and would like to transfer it to my Mac. However, it happens that I don't have my iPhone-to-USB cable with me today, so how I can I do it? If it was a photo I would just get it from my PhotoStream in iPhoto, but it seems videos don't appear there.

This has been asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/can-i-wirelessy-copy-my-videos-from-iphone-to-mac), but the accepted answer just says to buy an app. It's also been asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/transfer-video-from-iphone-to-mac-without-cable?rq=1), but the accepted answer says to email it. This doesn't work, because I get a message saying the video is too long and asking whether I want to select a shorter clip from it. (I do not.)

It seems unlikely to me that there's no way to do this with standard Apple software - so how can I do it without installing anything?

If it makes a difference I'm using Mountain Lion on a Macbook Pro and iOS 6 on an iPhone 5. I have an unlimited data plan.

Comment: I don't have my cable with me.

Comment: ...but supposing I did, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think I did that once already. Assuming I did, how would I then access the videos from my iPhone? In iTunes the only iPhone-related things I can find are the menu items File->Devices->Sync "Nathaniel's iPhone" and File->Devices->Transfer Purchases from "Nathaniel's iPhone", both of which are greyed out.

Comment: Nevermind above, it doesn't work. Do you have iMessage enabled? Simply send the video to yourself and you can open it on your Macbook.

Comment: That worked, but it massively lowered the quality compared to what I see on the iPhone screen, i.e. it converted my nice HD video into a tiny little SD one.

Answer (score 4):

I know you say you do not want to install. But you can get a free Dropbox account.

Install it on you Mac and iOS device.

Then in the iOS Dropbox.

Tap the **3 blue circles** in the Menu bar.

[image]

---

**Select the + Upload menu.**

---

[image]

---

Allow Dropbox to see you Photos if Asked.

Navigate to the camera roll or Album that contains you video.

Tap it/them to select it/them

Tap The Upload menu to upload.

Once done they should be on you Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run iPhoto just for that, and you're happy looking at the files at a slightly lower level, then [iFunBox](http://bit.do/http-i-funbox-com-ifunboxmac) is useful. It shows the Photo Album of the device as a digital camera (DCIM) directory so you can see all the files, then copy to/from your Mac.

There's a Mac version too, which has proved useful in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Send a message to yourself in Messages. You might need to create a conversation with your Apple ID on the iMac to see the incoming message but it seems to work.